# application android contact sync

Tags: android, android-contacts, google-contacts-api, android-syncadapter

**hi,
I am looking for application (apk) or php api can sync android contact with my database  mysql ,i want to sync every custmer in my site (database) to my phone contact

thinks,

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to take a look at this REST api:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/) seems to show how to do what you want.

Comment: some one like that with syncbook contact